# jQuery javascript autocomplete and managing ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple), Now in the hidden field I am trying to manage the ids of the item selected,

For example, consider this is the data set I have, [Apple:1, Mango:2, Coconut:3, Apple:4]

Now if I type `hello` it should print `hello` to hidden field now if I trigger autocomplete and select Apple from it hidden field should be `hello [Apple:1]`

So far all good, but if I delete `e` from `apple` from the main textbox hidden field should hold 
`hello appl` , It should also  allow to have multiple entries with same name (as shown here with 2 entries of `apple`)

Comment: How is hello related to apple? Can you post your code?

Comment: if I type `hello` it should print `hello` to hidden field now if I trigger autocomplete and select `Apple` from it hidden field should be `hello [Apple:1]`

Comment: In other word it should hold the id for selected terms and plain text for others also it should be able to handle change in the text

Comment: @JigarJoshi: Posting some code would go a long way here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it with a map data structure so if I select `abc` I will add it into map `{abc, 1}` now on change I am splitting it by space and I see if the word belongs to map if yes then replace it with its value